# How to use volume button to take a photo with a custom camera?

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation, volume

I would like it so when the user presses either volume button the app responds to this action and takes the photo.

I have accomplished something similar to this as I added a notification and when a volume button is pressed I linked it to execute the method for taking a photo, but the volume popup still shows. How could I disable the volume button temporarily like Snapchat does when taking a photo?

Here's the code I have so far:

view did load

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(volumeChanged:)
                                             name:@"AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"
                                           object:nil];
```

method

```
-(IBAction)volumeChanged:(id)sender{

[self takePhotoFromDevice:nil];

}
```

Comment: I could be wrong but I believe Apple rejects any app from the app store that uses the hardware for things that it wasn't meant to do.

Comment: Fair, but a huge number of camera apps (including their own camera) does this.

Comment: Yes, there is a successful workaround. The only condition that Apple has put forwards is that the main function of the volume key should not be obstructed.

Comment: do you have solution for hide system volume UI?

Answer (score 0):

The system volume overlay is suppressed when a `MPVolumeView` is displayed. `MPVolumeView` is a volume slider – think Apple Music, Spotify or similar.

You could add one as a subview but position it somewhere offscreen:

```
@import MediaPlayer;

// In viewDidLoad
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(-100, -100, 0, 0)];
[self addSubview:volumeView];
```

The only caveat here is that the *ringer* popup will display if the user has opted to change the ringer volume with buttons in Settings.